# Windows batch how to find file and run it with folder depth support

Tags: windows, batch-file, find

I am trying to find setup file in sub directory and run it as parametrized silent install. Subdirectory name changes constantly also I need to do it in depth = 1 because there are multiple setup files. For example:

```
root dir C:\temp
C:\temp\
|-\subdir1\setup.exe (want to run this one but it sometimes can be Setup.exe)
|-\subdir1\subsubdir1\setup.exe
|-\subdir1\subsubdir2\
|-\subdir1\subsubdir3\setup.exe
```

Tried to write script in powershell where full path to file was saved to variable and and injected to command but powershell has issues with running silent installation and in most cases they just fail to install correctly. No idea why. When running the same command from cmd it works perfectly fine. Sadly deleted it by mistake so cannot show code. And another issue is that powershell version varies for different Windows types so some internal command work and some do not.

Also tried to somehow modify this solution from similar answer:

```
for /f "delims=" %%i in ('dir /b /a-d /s C:\temp\setup.exe /someparams') do "%%~fi"
```

issue here is that `dir` does not support depth and this result in running all setup files in all sub directories one after another. No idea how to make it work just for one.

Right now I am trying to do the same as in powershell using batch and have this:

```
for /r C:\temp %%a in (*) do if "%%~nxa"=="setup.exe" set p=%%~dpnxa
if defined p (
start "%p% /silent /othervar"
) else (
echo Something did not work.
)
```

Right now I am stuck and have no idea how to achieve what I want. Hopefully someone can help.

Comment: Which of the two provided code snippets do you need help with? and what happens when you run it, which differs from your intent?

Comment: 1st is more simple so if it is possible to make it work with recursive dept to only first subdirectory then that would be awesome. Right now I am trying to make the second one work but have no idea how to implement recursive dept search in it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your first command erroneously inserts `/someparams` to the dir instead of checking the presence of a setup.exe and passing them to it.

The 2nd batch uses the `/r` and unwantedly recurses and finds all setup.exe in subsubdirs.

Use `For /D` to restrict to 1st level dirs

```
for /d %%a in ("C:\temp\*") do if exist "%%~fa\setup.exe" "%%~fa\setup.exe" /someparams
```

Or - if the setup.exe expects to find files/folders in the current dir - use :

```
for /d %%a in ("C:\temp\*") do if exist "%%~fa\setup.exe" (
    cd /D "%%~fa"
    setup.exe /someparams
)
```

Comment: This works great and does what I wanted, thanks a lot for help.

Comment: After a while I must say this works but not always. Today I did try to run InstallShield setup.exe like this ` for /d %%a in ("C:\temp\*") do if exist "%%~fa\setup.exe" "%%~fa\setup.exe" /silent ` and yes it does find the file but does not run it as it thorws '/silent is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file. I did try to modify it like so `"%%~fa\setup.exe" %1` and `"%%~fa\setup.exe" "%1" ` still this works partially it launches the setup but not in silent mode as GUI pops up and waits for user interaction.